# How to create PDF links that can be updated very quickly into future updated PDF files?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I have a pdf catalog with hundreds of items, divided by brand. The catalog will be updated very often.
Does anyone know of a way I can include some sort of links that would bring the viewer over to specific pages, or to specific brands - in a way I can very quickly and easily copy over to future updates of the pdf?
For ex: click the link for "A" and be brought to the brands starting with that letter.
I don't want to have to go through 60 links every time I update.
Any ideas for how I can accomplish something like this?
Any leads appreciated... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to do what you want is to create the in-document links already in the source document processor, e.g. LibreOffice Writer, Microsoft Word, Adobe InDesign, ...

Then when you export your document to PDF, the processor will make sure that the links are available and pointing to the correct place.

Comment: Thank you! Problem is that I'm getting the PDF. I don't have access to the original file. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not really, just that this would be much harder because how can a program uniquely identify, for example, where the "A" link should be and to which header it should point to? There may be a chance if the source application produces tagged PDF because then you would have some additional meta information.